# System size is 8 GB after Clean Install of Sierra

Tags: macos, disk-space

After I did a clean install of Sierra it first showed as 14 GB in size in "About My Mac Storage". After some few weeks it shows as 8 GB in size.

Why does happen like this and how do I fix it?

Comment: There is a problem and it is not showing the whole question.Please click 'improve this question'.Then see the whole question

Comment: I removed the less-than symbol from the body text to make your question complete.  As for your question, perhaps some behind-the-scenes macOS activity deleted hidden cache files, swap files, and other temporary files.

Comment: Yeah it could be because I was downloading many apps.

Comment: Before you can 'fix' it - how do you know one of those figures is 'broken' & which one?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: What do you mean with *System* size? The *System* size in "About My Mac > Storage > Manage > Recommendations - System" defaults to ~ 8.0-8.7 GB. The folder /System has a default size of ~ 5.5 GB and the whole system install ~ 10.5 GB (after some use but without sleepimage and swap).

Comment: Oh I did not know that but thanks anyways for your comment @klanomath.And my system folder is 7.91GB after 1 min of boot.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in size is similar to the High Sierra Installer, if you deleted the installer after the upgrade that might explain it